# How can I resize the root window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket, sys
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Whois Tool")
root.resizable(0, 0)

text = Text()
text1 = Text()

image = Image.open("hacker2.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = Label(root, image=photo)
label.pack()


text1.config(width=15, height=1)
text1.pack()

def button1():
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(("com.whois-servers.net", 43))
        s.send(text1.get("1.0", END) + "\r\n")
        response = ''
        while True:
            a = s.recv(4096)
            response += a
            if a == '':
                break
        s.close()
        text.insert(END, response)

def clear():
        text.delete("1.0", END)


b = Button(root, text="Enter", width=10, height=2, command=button1)
b.pack()

c = Button(root, text="Clear", width=10, height=2, command=clear)
c.pack()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
text.config(width=60, height=15)
text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
scrollbar.config(command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


root.mainloop()
```

How can I resize the root window, or how can I  resize an image to fit with the root window or button or lable and ect.. thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For a 500x500 window you would use

```
root.geometry("500x500")
```

As for image resizing, I do not believe Tkinter supports it. You would have to use a library such as [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to resize the image to the window resolution. -*[example resize code](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216637.html#)*-

Comment: The only resizing supported by Tkinter out of the box is by multiples of two.

Comment: @Bryan, I believe you, but I wasn't able to find any info on that after some rudimentary searching. Just out of curiosity, how would you implement that?

Comment: my bad. Tk allows you to zoom or scale an image, but that isn't exposed in the Tkinter interface.

Comment: this also moves the window to the absolute position 0,0 on the screen. how can i avoid this?

Comment: @peschü: if you haven't found it, and in reference to those after you:
the geometryformat is "width"x"height"+"x"+"y", so to have a 500x500 on x200 and y100 it would be "500x500+200+100"