# Getting Error For TKinter In pycharm And Python IDLE

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting error in this code. I can not under stand it
I also try to write code in this text but could not, Because I am getting error

[image]

Comment: Please do not use irrelevant tags.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1. Don't post/link to pictures of code/errors (see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Copy code/errors as text into your question. 2. Don't spam tags: [tag:c], [tag:php], and [tag:java] are not applicable to your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize the root window in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2261082)

Comment: As JohnnyMopp said: change `window.geometry(800*800)` to `window.geometry("800x800")`

Comment: Please don't Write Text with Random Upper case Letters. It is Very Annoying to Read.

Answer (score 0):

When resizing Tkinter windows, you must use the proper format: `<width>x<height>`. So, you should do `800x800`. You also need to make sure that it is a string, so like this: `root.geometry('800x800')`

Comment: Also you might want to add that it should be in a string